# Overpass API add a tag to output

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

can I make a request so that I can customize the output tags.

```
    [out:json];
(
  area[name="Braunschweig"];
  ) ->.a;
(
  area[postal_code="38114"];
  ) ->.b;
way(area.a)(area.b)[name="Celler Heerstraße"];
out geom;
```

This query will return me all the tags that the "Celler Heerstraße" has. Another tag is to be added in the output. This should carry the place in which the street is located. If I ask for a street in "Braunschweig" as in the example, "Braunschweig" should be included as an attribute in the tags in the file. Is this possible?

Comment: Also posted here: https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=72300

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "output to be appended". Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I changed the text.